# How to install Angular 2? Only Angular

Tags: angular

I'm following [this](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html) Angular 2 official tutorial. When I run `npm install` I get a folder called `node_modules` with 12.523 items and 66 MB . Which files are Angular? I'm completely new to this. I need only the Angular js files and core dependencies, where can I find them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/what-is-npm) is used to download dependencies to your project. It downloads the sources, but you need to add a reference to them in your HTML. In that tutorial, you can see how to achieve this a little later:

```
...
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>

<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.umd.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js">
...
```

Follow the tutorial carefully :)

Answer (score 1):

Use source files as usual
Build sources into one file and load them from html file

Comment: Which ones are Anglular source files?

Comment: @alejoss use links on sources in above answer, all of them are inside `node_modules` folder

Comment: Ok thnks, I thought those where the sources plus some extra unnesessary files.